# Definition of a smooth vector field along $\partial M$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

In the picture below, from the book I'm using, we find a definition of a smooth vector field along $\partial M$.
[image]

My doubt rest on why $p\in M$ but the local definition is for $q\in \partial M$.

Does the author mean that for smoothness, the coefficients of the vector field must have an $C^{\infty}$ extension to a neighbourhood of $p$? What's the objective of such a definition?

Comment: For the first one, it should be read as $X_q = \sum_i a^i(q) \partial/\partial x^i |_q$, $ q \in \partial M$ for arbitrary $q \in \partial M$ that contain in the chart. For the smoothness, i think there is a typo at the second sentence before the proposition. The point $p \in M$ should be $p \in \partial M$. This makes sense since domain of $X$ is $\partial M$.